# Paging / Sorting on GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview-sorting, scroll-paging

(this is another question, since my original post, I asked too many questions in one)

Let me state this first. I am pretty much completely new to ASP coding. I am working on a little side project that requires me to use ASP instead of PHP that I sort of did before. I have been looking at solutions for past 2 days, and have tried many things, but can't seem to get it to work with my code. I have been part of this site for some time, so I do know how it works. I would not be asking here if I wasn't already trying to do this on my own for some time. I have learned a huge amount of information about SQL on here, so I hope to do the same with ASP.

Question:

## Sorting/Paging

I know that I need the `OnPageIndexChanging="GridView1_PageIndexChanging" OnSorting="GridView1_Sorting"` and the Code Behind to make it work for my set otherwise I get the : "The GridView 'GridView1' fired event Sorting which wasn't handled." error. Just any solution I find out there, I just can't make it work within my code.

GridView1 :

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Width="265px" Height="22px" CssClass="myBox"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" OnClick="Button1_Click" Text="Search Fields" CssClass="myButton" />
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" OnPageIndexChanging="GridView1_PageIndexChanging" OnSorting="GridView1_Sorting" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="true" CellPadding="4" EnableModelValidation="True" EnableTheming="True" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None" Width="100%" style="margin-top: 0px; text-align: center;" AllowPaging="True" AllowSorting="True" >
    <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#284775" />
    <EditRowStyle BackColor="#999999" />
    <FooterStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
    <HeaderStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
    <PagerStyle BackColor="#284775" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
    <RowStyle BackColor="#F7F6F3" ForeColor="#333333" />
    <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#E2DED6" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
</asp:GridView>
```

Code Behind (DB name and Password taken out):

```
SqlConnection vid = new SqlConnection("Data Source=ENF;Initial Catalog=***Database Name***;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password=***Password***");
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        GridView1.DataSource = GetData();
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }
}

protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    String str = "SELECT ab.NAME as [Customer] ,ISNULL(ab.TELEPHONE1,'') as [Phone #] ,ISNULL(pb.NAME,'') as [Product] ,ISNULL(aeb.NEW_PRODUCTVERSION,'') as [Version] ,CASE WHEN ab.STATUSCODE = 1 THEN 'Active' ELSE 'Inactive' END as [Status] ,ISNULL('Sal : ' + c.SALUTATION + ' / ','') + ISNULL('Title : ' + c.JOBTITLE + ' / ','') + ISNULL(a.PRIMARYCONTACTIDNAME,'') as [Primary Contact] ,ISNULL(c.TELEPHONE1,'') as [Contact Phone] FROM ACCOUNTBASE ab LEFT JOIN ACCOUNTEXTENSIONBASE aeb on ab.ACCOUNTID = aeb.ACCOUNTID LEFT JOIN PRODUCTBASE pb on aeb.NEW_PRIMARYPRODUCTID = pb.PRODUCTID LEFT JOIN ACCOUNT a on ab.ACCOUNTID = a.ACCOUNTID LEFT JOIN CONTACT c on a.PRIMARYCONTACTID = c.CONTACTID WHERE ((ab.NAME LIKE '%' + @search + '%') OR (aeb.NEW_PRODUCTVERSION LIKE '%' + @search + '%') OR (pb.NAME LIKE '%' + @search + '%') OR (a.PRIMARYCONTACTIDNAME LIKE '%' + @search + '%')) ORDER BY ab.NAME";
    SqlCommand xp = new SqlCommand(str, vid);
    xp.Parameters.Add("@search", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = TextBox1.Text;

    vid.Open();
    xp.ExecuteNonQuery();
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
    da.SelectCommand = xp;
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    da.Fill(ds, "Name");
    GridView1.DataSource = ds;
    GridView1.DataBind();

    vid.Close();
}
```

Additional GetData()

```
private DataSet GetData()
{
    String str = "SELECT ab.NAME as [Customer] ,ISNULL(ab.TELEPHONE1,'') as [Phone #] ,ISNULL(pb.NAME,'') as [Product] ,ISNULL(aeb.NEW_PRODUCTVERSION,'') as [Version] ,CASE WHEN ab.STATUSCODE = 1 THEN 'Active' ELSE 'Inactive' END as [Status] ,ISNULL('Sal : ' + c.SALUTATION + ' / ','') + ISNULL('Title : ' + c.JOBTITLE + ' / ','') + ISNULL(a.PRIMARYCONTACTIDNAME,'') as [Primary Contact] ,ISNULL(c.TELEPHONE1,'') as [Contact Phone] FROM ACCOUNTBASE ab LEFT JOIN ACCOUNTEXTENSIONBASE aeb on ab.ACCOUNTID = aeb.ACCOUNTID LEFT JOIN PRODUCTBASE pb on aeb.NEW_PRIMARYPRODUCTID = pb.PRODUCTID LEFT JOIN ACCOUNT a on ab.ACCOUNTID = a.ACCOUNTID LEFT JOIN CONTACT c on a.PRIMARYCONTACTID = c.CONTACTID WHERE ((ab.NAME LIKE '%' + @search + '%') OR (aeb.NEW_PRODUCTVERSION LIKE '%' + @search + '%') OR (pb.NAME LIKE '%' + @search + '%') OR (a.PRIMARYCONTACTIDNAME LIKE '%' + @search + '%')) ORDER BY ab.NAME";
    SqlCommand xp = new SqlCommand(str, vid);
    xp.Parameters.Add("@search", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = TextBox1.Text;

    vid.Open();
    xp.ExecuteNonQuery();
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
    da.SelectCommand = xp;
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    da.Fill(ds, "Name");
    vid.Close();

    return ds;
}
```

Added this to Code Behind :

```
protected void GridView1_PageIndexChanging(object sender, EventArgs e)
```

{
 }

protected void GridView1_Sorting(object sender, GridViewSortEventArgs e)
 {
 }

Now, when clicking on the column name or the paging page, it just flashes the page, and nothing happens.

Comment: You say "I just can't make it work within my code" but you don't seen to have written even handlers for your events so there is nothing to work or not work.

Comment: I have tried so, that's where I get the stop. I know I need GridView1_Sorting and GridView1_Paging in my CodeBehind but any code I have found online and tried to adjust, just broke more things then it helped.

Comment: So add the broken code and explain what it does wrong. We can help fix broken code, we cannot help with nothing.

Answer (score 0):

you have to implement [Sorting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.sorting%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) event

```
<asp:GridView OnSorting="GridView1_Sorting" />

protected void GridView1_Sorting(object sender, GridViewSortEventArgs e)
{ 
    //sort the data
}
```

Comment: I have tried so, that's where I get the stop. I know I need GridView1_Sorting and GridView1_Paging in my CodeBehind but any code I have found online and tried to adjust, just broke more things then it helped.

Answer (score 0):

After I added following lines to page aspx.cs file, error gone away:

```
protected void GridView1_PageIndexChanging(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
 }

 protected void GridView1_Sorting(object sender, GridViewSortEventArgs e)
 {
 }
```

Comment: When doing that, it has no effect on the sorting at all. The page just flashes and everything is still the same

Comment: It is because in GridViewSortEventArgs there is no implementation of sorting. I propose to look at http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/246361/Handle-GridView-OnSorting-using-LINQ or https://books.google.com.ua/books?id=2wg5LCKuChcC&pg=PA425&lpg=PA425&dq=C%23+GridViewSortEventArgs&source=bl&ots=HktehHueIK&sig=LsCMdghYWpTh-cV-cmWFirW_qfo&hl=en&sa=X&ei=ARKTVKmGGoS8ygOzqYC4BQ&ved=0CFcQ6AEwCQ#v=onepage&q=C%23%20GridViewSortEventArgs&f=false